# What kind of role do the badges play on AskUbuntu?

Tags: discussion

If this site is supposed to be a question/answer forum let me forward this one. Tumbleweed badge awarded to me for a question that I posted and everybody else has ignored? What does that mean? Was my question asked wrong? Was it not significant enough for all of you guru's out there? Previously I asked another question on this site which earned me another badge, "Student", whatever that means. But that old profile of mine is not accessible by me already, so I had to create another profile (this one). People, humans, I am confused, my brothers and sisters. What's the point of this game, dear ones?

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong in being awarded a Tumbleweed. I have one too. You shouldnt take it seriously. We here have lot of fun answering serious questions. Badges are awarded depending on how serious your answers are.

There are also a few, that are just plain funny.  I always find a new one and sometimes it makes me smile, and sometimes it makes me wanna do something, to earn that badge. Coming back to your tumbleweed question, it is possible that no one has done what you are asking for. It might be possible, but people dont want to find an answer for it, because it is too simple to waste their time on, or too complicated to give an outright answer. You should just keep an open mind.

All the guys here are dedicated people, who make an effort to answer all the questions posted here. But you should remember, that they have a life beyond the forums, and AU might not always be a priority for some of them. So, just relax, come join the forum, and contribute to humanity, ie Ubuntu!

Comment: If you get a tumbleweed consider editing it to make it more detailed, easier to read, etc. It's hard to post a detailed question right off the bat without having to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Badges are designed as few 'gaming' devices on the site. The first that comes to mind is flair!

They show the community and other users accomplishments you've made in the community. While some badges are easier to get than others none are really trivial - It's not easy to ask a question that gets 'untouched' for a tumbleweed period of time, on the same note necromancer is to highlight those users taking care of tumbleweeds.

[image: Office Space photo]

> Brian has 37 pieces of flair.

Second, it's a gaming device. StackExchange is constantly improving the network and will occasionally add badges to help keep things interesting. Ideally there here to help users have objectives other than just answer questions for what basically amounts to no compensation (Outside of reputation and unicorn bucks)

[image]

So you can view each badge, what it means, and who has gotten it on the [Badges page](https://askubuntu.com/badges) each has it's own meaning and level of difficulty to achieve (Bronze is 'easiest', Silver is 'relatively hard', and Gold is 'got to really try hard to get this').

Answer (score 0):

Isn't somehow cool having an assortment of badges, if you're really honest?
It also shows how experienced a user is, although you can have a experienced new ask ubuntu user.